# Zabbix: Queue of items to be updated does not decrease (in administration tab)

Tags: zabbix

I have added over 20 hosts, but for some reason some items are stuck (counter does not go down)
[image]

if filter (top left drop list) Overview by Proxy, only the line the with 16 hanged items are left. what bother me is that i did not install or configured proxy

Answer (score 0):

[Queue Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJI1D.png)

Use the Details dropdown and see what items are delayed on which host. And from there verify if the configured item is correct and also try to use "Check now" to see if that updates the item.